# Adding Filters on Angular View

Tags: angularjs

I have created a view in Angular that shows deal records. The deal records have various attributes around them. One of them is a coupon Code.

What I am trying to do is add 3 links on top of the page. The first link is All Deals second is Coupon Codes and third is Deals.

The user by default sees all deals on page load. 
If a user clicks on Coupon Codes, I want to show only deals with Coupon Code != ''. 
If a user clicks on Deals, I want to show only deals with Coupon Code == ''

Here's what I have done so far. The below code is my view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="deals">
<head>
    <title>{{ $merchant_url_text }} AngularJS Coupons & Promo Codes</title>

    <!-- Load Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="<?= asset('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TRYSTIN</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-9">

            <div ng-controller="dealsController" ng-init="init({{$merchant_url_text}})">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$merchant_url_text}}">
                <h2>{{$merchant_url_text}} Promo Codes & Coupons</h2>


                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a data-ng-click="setSelected(0)" href="#">
                        All Deals
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a data-ng-click="setSelected(1)" href="#">
                        Coupon Codes
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a data-ng-click="setSelected(2)" href="#">
                        Deals
                    </a>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Deal Text</th>
                            <th>Coupon Code</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr ng-repeat="deal in deals ">
                        <td>@{{ deal.deal_id }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ deal.deal_text }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ deal.coupon_code }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- End of Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Load Javascript Libraries (AngularJS, JQuery, Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="<?= asset('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?= asset('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?= asset('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>

    <!-- AngularJS Application Scripts -->
    <script src="<?= asset('app/app.js') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?= asset('app/controllers/deals.js') ?>"></script>
</body>
```

The below code is my controller code

```
app.value('deals', '[]');


app.controller('dealsController', function($scope, $http, API_URL, deals) {

$scope.init = function(merchant_url_text) {
  $scope.merchant_url_text = merchant_url_text;
  //console.log("Inside Init: " + $scope.merchant_url_text);
  //retrieve deals listing from API
    $http.get(API_URL + merchant_url_text)
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.deals = response;
            this.deals = $scope.deals;
        });


}

$scope.setSelected = function (selection) {
    if (selection == 1) {
        var tempDeals = [];
        //console.log("selected: " + 1);
        angular.forEach(this.deals, function(deal){
            //console.log(deal.coupon_code);
            if(deal.coupon_code != '') {
               count ++;
               tempDeals.push(deal);
            }

        });
        console.log("Found " + count + " deals with coupon codes");
        $scope.deals = tempDeals;

    } else if (selection == 2){
        //console.log("selected: " + 2);
        var tempDeals = [];
        var count = 0;
        //console.log("selected: " + 2);
        angular.forEach(this.deals, function(deal){
            //console.log(deal.coupon_code);
            if(deal.coupon_code == '') {
               count ++;
               tempDeals.push(deal);
            }

        });
        console.log("Found " + count + " deals without coupon codes");
        $scope.deals = tempDeals;

    } else {
        $scope.deals = this.deals;
    }
    return false;
};


});
```

I am not able to get it working. Is this the right way to show some deals based on a filter click when all the deals have already been loaded or is there an easier way to do this.

Comment: Where is it not working? Are you getting errors or it just shows nothing? Try to log your $scope.deals object. Also, you might want a "master" deals object and then load $scope.deals with the ones you want to show. 
I suggest you to log (`console.log foo`) anything you want to check, so you can see if the filter is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find easier to query the server with the narrow results.

You can trigger a new "get" action from your server with a specific query parameter and do a proper search (usually db queries are easier to perform) and load your scope with the results.

Comment: So does that mean, every time i click on a filter I call the API with specific request. Since I am already loading all the data on my first page load, wouldn't it be easier to just filter on those results?

Comment: Definitely, it was just a suggestion, because sometimes it is not easy to filter at angular level, or you don't want to load the memory with a big data object from your server.